# babel-loader syntax error only for imported modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Initially I have the below **index.js** file that compiles and runs:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import text from './titles.json';

render(
    <div>
        <h1 id="title"
            className="header"
            style={{backgroundColor: 'turquoise', color: 'white', fontFamily: 'verdana'}}>
            {text.hello}
        </h1>
        <h1 id="title"
            className="header"
            style={{backgroundColor: 'brown', color: 'white', fontFamily: 'verdana'}}>
            {text.goodbye}
        </h1>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
)
```

However, when I separate out the components in a separate file (lib.js), I get "Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:1) for lib.js. **I can't see why babel is not taking care of the transpiling once I move the components into lib.js**. Please help (I'm new to React, Webpack, Babel).

**lib.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import text from './titles.json'

export const hello = {
    <h1 id="title"
        className="header"
        style={{backgroundColor: 'turquoise', color: 'white', fontFamily: 'verdana'}}>
        {text.hello}
    </h1>
}

export const goodbye = {
    <h1 id="title"
        className="header"
        style={{backgroundColor: 'brown', color: 'white', fontFamily: 'verdana'}}>
        {text.goodbye}
    </h1>
}
```

**modified index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { hello, goodbye } from './lib.js';

render(
    <div>
        {hello}
        {goodbye}
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
)
```

Here is my webpack config file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: require("path").resolve("dist/assets"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "assets"
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: "./dist",
        port: 3000
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["latest", "react", "stage-0"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export const hello = {
    <h1 id="title"
        className="header"
        style={{backgroundColor: 'turquoise', color: 'white', fontFamily: 'verdana'}}>
        {text.hello}
    </h1>
}
```

The `{...}` are interpreted as an object literal. You cannot put JSX inside an object literal, just like you cannot put arbitrary code inside an object literal.

E.g. this throws a similar error:

```
export const hello = {
 1 + 1
}
```

If you want to export the React element, then do just that. Remove the `{...}`:

```
export const hello = 
    <h1 id="title"
        className="header"
        style={{backgroundColor: 'turquoise', color: 'white', fontFamily: 'verdana'}}>
        {text.hello}
    </h1>;
```

---

*Inside* JSX, `{...}` have a different meaning. E.g. in

```
<span>{1+1}</span>
```

the `{...}` let the parser know that the content is a JavaScript expression.